# Passing TensorFlow tensors to a layer, but not as arguments... what is this practice called?

Tags: python, tensorflow

When passing a tensor to a layer, the tensor can be put after the layers brackets rather than within the brackets.  Does this type of parameter passing have a name?

```
**from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers

# Define a tensor
input_tensor = keras.Input(shape=(5, 10))
print("input_tensor...  type:", type(input_tensor), " shape: ", input_tensor.shape)


#Flattten the tensor - the first axis (the batch dimension) will not be changed
#Example 1
# Why do I put the inputs tensor at the end? What is this practice called?
flat_tensor1 = layers.Flatten()(inputs)
print("\nflat_tensor1...  type:", type(flat_tensor1), " shape: ", flat_tensor1.shape)


#Example 2 
flat_layer = layers.Flatten()
print("\nflat_layer...    type: ", type(flat_layer))

flat_tensor2 = flat_layer(inputs)
print("flat_tensor2...  type:", type(flat_tensor2), " shape: ", flat_tensor2.shape)**
```

Output:

```
input_tensor...  type: <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'>  shape:  (None, 5, 10)
        
flat_tensor1...  type: <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'>  shape:  (None, 50)
        
flat_layer...    type:  <class 'tensorflow.python.keras.layers.core.Flatten'>
flat_tensor2...  type: <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'>  shape:  (None, 50)
```

This Stack Overflow post is useful but doesn't explain reasons
['Tensor' object has no attribute 'lower'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53153790/tensor-object-has-no-attribute-lower)

Comment: I don’t know a lot about tensorflow, but it looks like currying. Or perhaps Flatten() is a callable class, and you are first constructing it, then calling it

Comment: @Mel It is the Functional API. You can find it [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/functional?hl=en)