# data_format = value.lower(),error:'Tensor' object has no attribute 'lower'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am fine-tuning a DCGAN. When I run this code:

```py
tf.keras.layers.Flatten(
                tf.abs(tf.multiply(self.mask, self.G) - tf.multiply(self.mask, self.images))), 1)
```

it turns out error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train-dcgan.py", line 39, in <module>
    is_crop=False, checkpoint_dir=FLAGS.checkpoint_dir)

  File "E:\dcgan-completion.tensorflow-master\dcgan-completion.tensorflow-master\model.py", line 81, in __init__
    self.build_model()

  File "E:\dcgan-completion.tensorflow-master\dcgan-completion.tensorflow-master\model.py", line 137, in build_model
    tf.abs(tf.multiply(self.mask, self.G) - tf.multiply(self.mask, self.images))), 1)

  File "D:\anaconda\envs\labelme\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\layers\core.py", line 588, in __init__
    self.data_format = conv_utils.normalize_data_format(data_format)

  File "D:\anaconda\envs\labelme\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\utils\conv_utils.py", line 191, in normalize_data_format
    data_format = value.lower()

AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

My tensorflow version is 2.1.0,but in this project,most of code use tensorflow 1.x,hope you can tell me the reason of error,thank you a lot!

Comment: Can you show the code you wrote?

Comment: try tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(tf.abs(tf.multiply(self.mask, self.G)) instead. Here's a link to a similar issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53153790/tensor-object-has-no-attribute-lower

Answer (score 0):

Flatten layer should be

```
tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(tf.abs(tf.multiply(self.mask, self.G) - tf.multiply(self.mask, self.images))), 1)
```

For more details please refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53154110/14290681)